# Was Galadriel's temptation of Boromir instrumental to his fall?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

We know Galadriel tempted the members of the Fellowship, did she tempt Boromir with visions of taking the Ring and saving Gondor?

In the books, Boromir willingly accepts the judgement of the council that the Ring should be destroyed, but after the meeting with Celeborn and Galadriel his personality seems to change.

***Was the temptation offered by Galadriel in some way responsible for Boromir's fall?***

Comment: I'd just like to thank you for changing my view of Galadriel. I never thought she could be so evil. But she truly is of the house of Fëanor! Even if she lived in Menegroth for years!! I'd gone into the answer with the same viewpoint as Daniel but how that viewpoint has changed!

Comment: You have two conflicting answers in the sense that one says "No" and the other says "It's likely", but they're actually answering two different questions: "did she plant the idea?" and "did she tempt him with the Ring?" respectively. In the future, you should ask questions in a way that all answers are about the same thing.

Comment: @isnane better?

Comment: Sure, but now Daniel's answer doesn't make sense because you changed your question. You also misquoted my username, so I didn't get your ping. But I won't neg you further.

Comment: This was all part of Galadriel's plan of lifting her ban and getting back to Valinor. Did you notice how she almost defeated Sauron _too easily_ in Dol Guldur? Plans within plans.

Comment: @void_ptr It is unclear if Galadriel was under the Ban at this point, if at all. Later writings suggest she _refused_ the pardon after the War of Wrath, other texts say she came to Middle-earth separately from Fëanor and was never under the Ban at all.

Comment: @void_ptr - Ha! I *knew* she was Bene Gesserit! -- The *Witch of Lothlórien* to be sure! :D

Comment: @user23715 - Which poses a question - who was defeated in the end? A master, or an apprentice?

Comment: Well, didn't you see her in blue face mode when she attacked Dol Goldur along with Dr Who, Agent Smith and Count Dooku?  She's obviously evil.

Comment: Next NYT headline: _Anonymous sources say Galadriel "may have ties" with Sauron_

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### It's likely, but not certain

I believe it is likely Galadriel tempted him with the ring, and in doing so re-ignited a pre-existing idea to take the ring, but to be clear lets break this down into three parts.

- Boromir at the Council of Elrond
- Boromir after setting off
- Boromir after being tempted

#### Boromir at the Council of Elrond

Boromir pleas for the ring to go to Minas Tirith, to help Gondor in its defense against Mordor.

> “ Why should we not think that the Great Ring has come into our hands to serve us in the very hour of need? Wielding it the Free Lords of the Free may surely defeat the Enemy. That is what he most fears, I deem.”

However after it's decided that the ring will go to Mordor, Boromir seems to be content with the decision.

> “So be it,’ he said. ‘Then in Gondor we must trust to such weapons as we have. And at the least, while the Wise ones guard this Ring, we will fight on.”

#### Boromir after setting off

After setting off Boromir pays no special attention to Frodo, playing his part in the Fellowship, carrying faggots of wood to keep everyone alive, and carrying Hobbits through the snow. It is not until after talking to Galadriel that he makes mention of the Ring again.

#### Boromir after being tempted

> “To me it seemed exceedingly strange,’ said Boromir. ‘Maybe it was only a test, and **she thought to read our thoughts for her own good purpose; but almost I should have said that she was tempting us**, and offering what she **pretended to have the power to give.** It need not be said that I refused to listen. The Men of Minas Tirith are true to their word.’ But what he thought that the Lady had offered him Boromir did not tell.
> And as for Frodo, he would not speak, though **Boromir pressed him with questions**. ‘She held you long in her gaze, Ring-bearer,’ he said.
> ‘Yes,’ said Frodo; ‘but whatever came into my mind then I will keep there.’
> ‘Well, have a care!’ said Boromir. ‘I do not feel too sure of this Elvish Lady and her purposes.”

It would seem that Boromir had been tempted, and quickly went into denial of the fact. He seemed to be trying to solve what Galadriel was doing, and may have been tempted by the Ring, saying *pretended to have the power to give*. Boromir is fully aware she could not give the Ring as she pleases and this may be what he's suggesting. Boromir also suddenly has a great interest in Frodo, and what she said to him while staring at him.

It is undeniable that this is a turning point for Boromir, where his temptation for the Ring grows tremendously. This is supported by his obsession with the Ring as they paddled down the Anduin. But whether this is due to Galadriel's temptation or not is unclear, although it is quite likely.

> Merry and Pippin in the middle boat were ill at ease, for **Boromir sat muttering to himself, sometimes biting his nails, as if some restlessness or doubt consumed him**, sometimes seizing a paddle and driving the boat close behind Aragorn’s. Then Pippin, who sat in the bow looking back, **caught a queer gleam in his eye, as he peered forward gazing at Frodo.**

It seems clear from the final chapters of the First Book that Boromir has become **obsessed** with Frodo, which I now believe is likely due to Galadriel's temptation.

Comment: +1, this answer has made my understanding of both characters way more enjoyable, and has completely "opened" my eyes to the evil/mischievous ways of Galadriel, which would make Loki blush. **Please, can we make this canon?**

Comment: *"The Quest stands upon the edge of a knife. I mean, if it wasn't before, I'll make sure it is now"*

Comment: 1) You seem to imply in your comments that Galadriel did this on purpose, going so far as calling her "evil", yet your answer makes no mention of this. 2) You also write that Galadriel "re-ignited a pre-existing idea", but the answer implies that he didn't care prior to meeting her. I find your answer somewhat confusing.

Comment: This is like saying a therapist getting you to open up and examine your emotional problems is responsible for your own thoughts. The sentences immediately preceding the quote above speaks about how she opens them up to the choice between the hard quest taken reluctantly and their deepest desire. The desire is theirs not hers.

Comment: I do not agree with the interpretation that Boromir was content after the council's decision. He strikes me multiple times as someone who is borderline sarcastic, as in 'yeah sure I am fine with your decision. Guard this ring while we fend off the hordes of mordor, no problem for me!'

Comment: Interesting.  Is it your contention that Boromir felt that Galadriel offered him the Ring?  I always thought she showed him on the throne of Gondor. If he thought the Ring would somehow get him there, maybe that's why he became obsessed with Frodo from that point. I never considered that Galadriel planted that idea in his head.

Comment: Everything I read here is consistent with Galadriel tempting Boromir not to bring about his fall, but to bring his buried desire for the Ring to the surface, maybe bringing a hidden problem into the open. It's hard to imagine what an 'evil' Galadriel would have gained from Boromir's fall, and easy to imagine how much damage Boromir could have done had he arrived with the Rinbearer in Minas Tirith

Comment: An additional point - the Fellowship encounters Galadriel after losing Gandalf. The purpose and leadership of the Fellowship must be reevaluated. Boromir now sees an 'easy' path to Gondor, without as much need of the rest of the Fellowship, so can imagine once again bringing the Ring to Gondor. Of course his lust for the ring would be reignited, Galadriel or not. I can't put that on Galadriel's shoulders.

Comment: This answer is wrong at every level. It shows no understanding of the characters, nor the nature of temptation. -- This answer is literally the inverse of the correct answer. -- Sorry to be harsh but if I don't make it this concise the criticism would be longer than your answer. No joke.

Comment: "whether this is due to Galadriel's temptation or not is unclear, although it is quite likely." **Why** is it quite likely? It's certainly clear that Boromir underwent a considerable and sudden change in his thoughts about the ring after Lorien, but yI don't think you've adequately supported your "quite likely". (I'm not sure how much I agree with your answer.)

Comment: -1 This answer tries to reach too far, and fails in my opinion. Boromir is a tragic character, and his flaws are all his own. Galadriel is blameless here.

Comment: I agree that she deliberately tempted him, and that it likely contributed to his actions at the falls of Rauros. I disagree that her intentions were in any way evil and I don't think we can know whether Boromir would have tried to take the ring even if he'd never met her. I interpret her testing/tempting of the fellowship as a crucible for their hearts. Perhaps all the choices at Rauros were influenced by her crucible: Frodo mistrusting the rest of the party, but Sam knowing in his heart he is true, and perhaps Aragorn, Legolas, and Gimli doubting their resistance of the ring.

Comment: @ToddWilcox probably has the most accurate view on the matter.  Galadriel wasn't infallible, and through her motives were almost certainly for the good of Middle Earth and the Fellowship, she probably did set the stones in motion for what happened at Rauros.  At least Boromir was able to redeem himself later.

Comment: I think @ToddWilcox should offer that as an answer; perhaps taking my answer into consideration — especially the “there is in her and in this land no evil” bit?  My answer addresses the previous version of the question and was posted too late.

Comment: @DJClayworth has the right of it, I think. It may be that Galadriel "caused" Boromir's betrayal by triggering him to act on ideas he already had. But it seems a stretch to suggest she purposefully tempted him. I very much like the idea that it may be the curse of Feanor still at work.

Answer (score 77):

No. Boromir had been tempted by the Ring ever since he first saw it in Rivendell. Sam, for one, saw this clearly, as he explains to Faramir at Henneth Annûn:

> [Said Sam]. 'It strikes me that folk takes their peril with them into Lórien, and finds it there because they've brought it. (...) Now Boro—' He stopped and went red in the face.
>
> 'Yes? *Now Boromir* you would say?' said Faramir. 'What would you say? He took his peril with him?'
>
> 'Yes sir, begging your pardon, and a fine man as your brother was, if I may say so. But you've been warm on the scent all along. Now I watched Boromir and listened to him, from Rivendell all down the road – looking after my master, as you'll understand, and not meaning any harm to Boromir – and it's my opinion that in Lórien he first saw clearly what I guessed sooner: what he wanted. From the moment he first saw it he wanted the Enemy's Ring!'
>
> <sub>*The Two Towers*, chapter 5, "The Window on the West"</sub>

Comment: The perfect quote! Perhaps also "'I should have said that she was ... offering what she pretended to have the power to give. It need not be said that I refused to listen. ...' But **what he thought that the Lady had offered him** Boromir did not tell."

Comment: The second part doesn't correspond to your definitive no. "He first saw clearly" who, Boromir? If that's the case then the answer is Yes or Maybe

Comment: **(Tinfoil hat mode ON)** *"and it's my opinion that in Lórien he (Boromir?) first saw clearly what I guessed sooner"* After reading this question, now I suspect that Galadriel gave Boromir a complicity nod, which he understood as her "blessing" to try and seize the Ring. Why would she do that? Well, because she is petty (*I will diminish, and go into the West, and remain Galadriel.... so f&%# Middle Earth!!*).

Comment: @xDaizu And I disagree with you. Not only would it be completely out of character for Galadriel, but there are no texts that support this. In fact, Gandalf says "[she] told me that [Boromir] was in peril" when he first meets Aragorn as the White Wizard.

Comment: @xDaizu: No. she is not petty, she passed her test. She finally realizes that her clinging to middle earth in a misguided attempt at ordering her own realm and the pride which held her to that ideal was wrong and it is time for her to let go. The whole mythology is centered on The Fall through the corruptive desire to order and control. I mean, even Sauron was "less evil for having served another."

Comment: I read the books but can't recall the details, but in the movies Boromir said Galadriel had offered him "hope", but that he couldn't see it.  Boromir is secretly despairing for his people, and doesn't believe Galadriel had anything to offer to help save them.  He saw the Ring as the only way to save them, and thus fell to the Ring's temptation, not Galadriel's.

Comment: @xDaizu That's completely unsupported by anything written in The Lord of the Rings, and seems like a total misreading of her character... It seems like you're projecting a pet theory / fanfic.

Comment: @xDaizu All the bearers of the eleven rings, and many of the wise besides, must know that either way things play out all of the rings of power are nearing their end. Either Sauron regains the One and the Three are laid bare, or the One is destroyed and the Three become little more than jewelry. The only other option is that someone strong thinks they can master the One and do good with it, which is the test Galadriel passes. She knows all work done with the One is corrupted. So her ring will become useless or corrupted, and she will diminish in power, and pass into the West one way or another.

Comment: Just a note, my comment was supposed to say "elven" but was autocorrected. People out there going "eleven rings? What eleven rings?" Running through the old song trying to figure out what the heck I'm saying. "Lets see nine rings for mortal men, yes yes. Um seven for the dwarven lords yes. Three for the elves, and one for the dark lord on his dark throne ok. Well maybe it's the seven plus the three plus the one which is eleven but that makes no *sense*". Anyway, my apologies if anyone was super confused.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Thanks for the clarification indeed. The number of rings didn't match for eleven. By the way, adding some rings is a great opportunity for fan-fic or roleplay : adding a set of 5 rings, for example...

Comment: When Sam says that to Faramir, he does have the benefit of hindsight, knowing (from Frodo) how Boromir went mad in the end.

Comment: Galadriel's behaviour in the War of the Ring is is explicitly commended as a main reason for her readmission into The West. That would not have been the case if she had tried to sabotage the Ring's journey. And let's not forget she had a much better chance to cause evil when **she was offered the Ring**.

Answer (score 6):

### Movie-based answer

I haven't read the book but when the Fellowship enter the Lothlórien and come up to meet Celeborn and Galadriel, she enters Borormir's mind, making him realize that his beloved people are in great danger. That vision makes Boromir reconsider the power he could possibly acquire if the ring was in his possession (and then how he could save his people from Mordor). He later confesses to Aragorn the vision he had and his fear regarding the future of Gondor.

Galadriel knows how humans are attracted by the power of the ring and could have cast this vision inside Boromir's mind in order to push him to try to steal the ring from Frodo when they were alone, making Frodo realize that the only way he could achieve his quest was on his own (or at least with someone he trust more than everything like Sam) without the threat of humans' avidity for power (the same thing reoccurs later with Faramir). I think Galadriel was trying to help Frodo rather than the Fellowship itself and that she already planned Boromir's decadence, possibly even his future sacrifice.

Comment: Is your answer based on the movie only?

Comment: @TimSparrow Yes, I didn't read the book, so I only based my answer on movie fact, i can't assure its total fiability.

Comment: The book is quite different, especially in Faramir's reaction to having the Ring within his reach.

Comment: The movie did have a somewhat tense scene on the slopes of Caradhras where Boromir almost had the ring, and there are likely statements by Boromir during the council to imply a pre-Galadriel interest in the ring.

Comment: The book is pretty, pretty, pretty good

Comment: You should give the book a chance.  Or, at least, sample the mostly excellent BBC audio dramatization in 13 episodes.

Comment: Galadriel's characterization in the movies, while not bad, is way less subtle than in the book. The episode of The Mirror of Galadriel is both better and more powerful than the pretty hamfisted scene from the movie. Like others have said, you should give the book a try.

Comment: The book was voted the best book of the 20th century by some hoity toity group of literature nerds, which means it beat out Harper Lee, Hemingway, Toni Morrison, William Golding, and so many other giants of English literature. What's amazing is how it's also so much more fun to read than most of those luminaries. There is no work of fiction I would more highly recommend to everyone in the world in any medium than the book version of *The Lord of the Rings*.

Comment: Althougth I think the movies are excellent (and actually the best trilogy I've ever seen), I never had the chance to give the books a try whereas I know I'm not gonna regret it. Thanks guys! I'm gonna take your advice more seriously and read the books! ;)